# Segfault while allotting 2D array using double dimensional pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working on a codechef practice problem http://www.codechef.com/problems/STEPUP#

I'm trying to set up a 2D array using pointers to accept the data and enter in into the 2D array as i receive it using scanf.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int m,n,i,k,j;
    int ex;
    scanf("%d",&ex);
    for(i=0;i<ex;i++)
    {
        int **edgegraph=NULL,temp1,temp2;
        scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
        edgegraph=malloc(m*sizeof(int));
        for(k=0;k<m;k++)
        {
            *(edgegraph+k)=malloc(m*sizeof(int));
            if(!*(edgegraph+k))
                exit(0);
        }

        for(k=0;k<m;k++)
        {
            scanf("%d %d",&temp1,&temp2);                           
            *(*(edgegraph+m*temp1)+temp2)=1;            
        }

        for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<m;j++)
                printf("%d ",*(*(edgegraph+m*i)+j));
            printf("\n");   
        }   
    }
}
```

The error i get is 
    (gdb) run
    Starting program: /home/vishwa/codechef/valid 
    2
    2 2
    1 2

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040079d in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffded8) at validedge.c:24
24                  *(*(edgegraph+m*temp1)+temp2)=1;    
(gdb) quit
```

What I intend to do is create an m*m matrix, set all valid edges to 1 and then sort in ascending order of number of edges. I'm unsure if this will solve the problem, but would like to know where I'm messing up.

Comment: can you explain what `n` is that you read in the first scanf?

Comment: @MattMcNabb n is the number of vertices, m the number of edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You malloc the wrong number of bytes: `edgegraph=malloc(m*sizeof(int));` should have `malloc(m * sizeof(int *));` . To avoid this sort of error you can use the following pattern:

```
ptr = malloc( N * sizeof *ptr );
```

which always allocates N of whatever `ptr` is a pointer to.

Next, the syntax `x[y]` is much simpler to read than `*(x+y)` especially when the expressions get complicated. Using that syntax would have avoided the mistake  `dconman` points outs.   You seem to have put an extra `m *` into your calculation where it is not required.

Also you mix up `m` and `n` later in your code. To avoid this sort of error, use more descriptive variable names.

---

So a fixed version of your allocation code could look like:

```
if ( 2 != scanf("%d %d",&num_edges, &num_vertices) )
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

edgegraph = malloc( num_vertices * sizeof *edgegraph );

for (int vertex = 0; vertex < num_vertices; ++vertex)
{
    edgegraph[vertex] = malloc( num_vertices * sizeof **edgegraph );
    if ( edgegraph[vertex] == NULL )
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Note that it is possible to replace that malloc series with a single allocation:

```
int (*edgegraph)[num_vertices] = malloc( num_vertices * sizeof *edgegraph );
```

---

Moving onto your code to read edges. You wrote `for(k=0;k<m;k++)` however I think you meant `n` there. Using more descriptive variable names and the `x[y]` syntax:

```
for(int edge = 0; edge < num_edges; ++edge)
{
    if ( 2 != scanf("%d %d",&temp1,&temp2) )
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if ( temp1 < 0 || temp1 >= num_vertices || temp2 < 0 || temp2 >= num_vertices )
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   // maybe display an error message

    edgegraph[temp1][temp2] = 1;
    edgegraph[temp2][temp1] = 1;   // add this if undirected graph!
}
```

---

Now the final loop, `for(i=0;i<m;i++)`. You have used the same variable `i` as control variable for this loop and for your outer loop. To avoid this sort of error, use scoped control variables:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_edges; ++i)
```

Finally you will need to free the memory you `malloc`'d at the end of each time around the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are so close: lose the `m*` in your expressions to access  an array element.  Remember, you set up your 2d array as an array of rows, each with its own pointer (you allocated each independently).

Comment: I made that edit. I'm still segfaulting at the same line and with a very similar error.
'    Starting program: /home/vishwa/codechef/valid 
    2
    2 2
    1 2
    2 1

    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x0000000000400791 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffded8) at     validedge.c:22
    22             *(*(edgegraph+temp1)+temp2)=1; '

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

```
*(*(edgegraph+m*temp1)+temp2)=1;
```

should be

```
*(*(edgegraph+temp1)+temp2)=1;
```

And the same change where you do that later in your code.
Is there a reason you are not using array indices?

EDIT

here is my input

```
2
10
10
4 3
4 9
7 3
3 7
4 3
4 5
7 4
3 5
9 0
5 2
```

And I got this output

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: yeah, I get the size later and it can be upto 10000, so I can't allot it beforehand.
If I were allocating a flat m*m*sizeof(int) bytes, should I be using the m then?

Comment: Edit: Tried that, now getting 
Starting program: /home/vishwa/codechef/valid 
2
2 2
1 2
2 1

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400791 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffded8) at validedge.c:22
22             *(*(edgegraph+temp1)+temp2)=1;

Comment: Are your values outside the size of the array? Remember than in an array of length n, valid indices are 0 to n-1. You can use the [] to access array elements regardless of if you use them to allocate it. They do what you are doing behind the scenes.

Comment: Isn't the 3rd for loop supposed to be `k<n` ? otherwise this code works for me. Just make sure that the numbers you enter after m are always strictly less than `m`

Comment: Why do you say k<n? I'm setting an m*m matrix and that's why both loops are k<m. What do you mean when you say the code works for you? What do you get as an output?

Comment: Your third loop asks for valid indices and sets them to one, the number of valid indices could be anything from 0 to m*m. I will edit with what I got.